# natbib \citet/p fields not 'active'

Tags: texstudio, auto-completion

This is not a big issue but I wander why it happens.
When I open my tex file in TeXstudio, in which I have a lot of references (using `natbib`), the fields in `{}` are not active immediately, and the package does not seem to work [say if I write `\citet`, it does not get recognised].

If I build the document and the bibliography a couple of times it then works, but the citation keys become green (active) only if I click on them and for instance delete and rewrite a letter, or add a comma and then remove it at the end.

Do you know why this happens and if there is a solution to have the package active immediately?
thank you!
Best
Grig

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example with bibliography ([MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: It sounds like you're describing the features of whatever editor you're using, but you don't actually say which editor that is (i.e. what is the name of the program you're writing the code in).

Comment: Sorry, it's Texstudio